# Using Python to search string where a number iterates

Tags: python, google-search

I'm trying to write a script that will search a string in google, loop and iterate the number in the string, and print the top links. I have this:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json as m_json

for x in range(3, 5):
    query = '"Amazon Best Sellers Rank: #' + str(x) + ' in Kitchen & Dining": Amazon.com'
    query = urllib.parse.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
    response = urllib.request.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read().decode()
    json = m_json.loads ( response )
results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']   # was URL in the original and that threw a name error exception
    print ( title + '; ' + url )
```

I'm getting this error:
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" on line 10, results = ...

Answer (score 0):

**Same question** Was posted by you beforetwo months and now again you are posting that [Link to your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023259/python-script-that-runs-an-iterating-google-search-and-prints-top-results-and-li)

And by the way  the answer to your question is also has been provided already on stackoverflow.

But again I am posting the code for you . 
And using your code only I am getting the desired result in Python 2.7 .

```
import urllib
import json as m_json

for x in range(3, 5): 
    query = 'x mile run'
    query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
    response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
    json = m_json.loads ( response )
    results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
    for result in results:
        title = result['title']
        url = result['url']   
        print ( title + '; ' + url )
```